# Transmission of additional ASCII characters when transferring file content with Xmodem

Tags: java, ascii, xmodem

I am currently working on a project in which I want to send file content (.txt document) via Xmodem to a COM port.

So far, so good. Now I noticed, however, that at the beginning and at the end of the transferred file content additional ASCII characters are transferred, which I must not and do not want to have there in this case.

First line of the text file: þ! <-- This should only contain the exclamation mark (before the exclamation mark there is a ä3/4)
Last line of the text file: enQ <-- This should be an “end”

```
//  In order to 4278 Data is transmitted in the form of byte blocks 
private final int SECTOR_SIZE = 4278;  //4278
```

I have adjusted the number of transmitted characters in the script so far, so that should not be the problem. Of course, I can be wrong, as I am still relatively inexperienced in the field of Xmodem.

For this reason, I would like to try my luck here and ask if anyone has any tips for me on how to fix the problem.

You can find the used script on this website:

https://ofstack.com/Java/19989/implement-the-xmodem-protocol-using-java.html

(The value in line 16 was changed (see above))

Comment: First tip: show your code when you ask for help.

Comment: What are the actual decimal values of the extra characters?

Comment: At the Beginning: 1 1 254

Comment: At the end it is decimal: 81

Comment: @Kayaman I wanted to, but it was formatted weird and got really confusing.

Comment: @Kayaman I added the link to the code in my question.

Comment: But you changed the sector size. [Xmodem's sector size is 128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMODEM) and you just decided to change it. No wonder it doesn't work. It's kinda like if you paint over the speed limit and set it to 1000, the police is still going to pull you over.

Comment: @Kayaman Ok, thanks. I mean the file content was transfered correctly, with the exception of the additional ASCII-Characters. When I change it to 128, it stops after 7 lines od transfering and the additional ASCII-Characters are again there.